# Unable to install github packages from R, "could not resolve proxy"

Tags: r, github, rstudio

I recently changed some settings in the Rstudio configuration while tryng to set up a conection with conda, I tried to return all the settings to default and now I can not install github packages anymore, when I try to install a package I recieve the error

```
    Error: Failed to install 'unknown package' from GitHub:
  Could not resolve proxy: proxy.server.com
```

I tried using  `devtools::install_github()` and `remotes::install_github()` both are giving me the same error. Is there something i can chek to see if the connection is ok? I am not having any other issues when installing packages from CRAN or pulling and pushing to github from Rstudio. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to check your connection is try it out.
You can check your connection by push a small change to another RStudio project. After that you can check the logs in RStudio (accessible via help/Diagnostics/Show log files.

Comment: Thanks for answering, the connection for pulling/pushing works fine, the problem I have is when isntalling packages from github

Comment: You are trying to install the package via a proxy which is not existing. Please have a look onto Tools/Global Options/Packages/Management: Can you see a check mark at the option Use Internet Explorer library/proxy for http?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I tried both with checked and unchecked and still have the same error message

Comment: OK. Could be you've set the http_proxy environment variable to the /R_HOME/etc/Rprofile.site file so it applies to your request:

Sys.setenv(http_proxy = "http://proxy.server.com")

Comment: I found the problem, I had some sttings in the .Renviron regarding the use of a proxy. I just deleted those and its working now. Thanks so much for your help!!!